# How do you fix event error 7024 in SQL Server to allow a connection from an application server to a database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, events, odbc, windows-server

We are having issues connecting our SQL database to an application server. We contacted the application company, and they stated the service "MSSQLSERVER" isn't running, the agent isnt running either but they did not state that needed to be running.

We are getting Event Error 7024 saying that data is invalid. The name of the instance is "SQL2012SVR/TWOSOURCE" and we are able to start that service.

[image]

Comment: It sounds sql server process is dying on that machine. That error code of "Data is invalid" isn't terribly helpful. Is there anything in the logs. I think those are at `Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL\Log`.